# Python Stops Running then causes memory to spike

Tags: python, django, memory, pycharm

I'm running a large Python3.7 script using PyCharm and interfaced by Django that parses txt files line by line and processes the text. It gets stuck at a certain point on one particularly large file and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Once it gets stuck, the memory that PyCharm uses according to Task Manager runs up to 100% of available over the course of 5-10 seconds and I have to manually stop the execution (memory usage is low when it runs on other files and before the execution stops on the large file).

I've narrowed the issue down to the following loop:

```
i = 0
for line in line_list:
    label_tmp = self.get_label(line)  # note: self because this is all contained in a class
    if label_tmp in target_list:
        index_dict[i] = line
    i += 1
    print(i)  # this is only here for diagnostic purposes for this issue
```

This works perfectly for a handful of files that I've tested it on, but on the problem file it will stop on the 2494th iteration (ie when i=2494). It does this even when I delete the 2494th line of the file or when I delete the first 10 lines of the file - so this rules out a bug in the code on any particular line in the file - it will stop running regardless of what is in the 2494th line.

I built self.get_label() to produce a log file since it is a large function. After playing around, I've begun to suspect that it will stop running after a certain number of actions no matter what. For example I added the following dummy lines to the beginning of self.get_label():

```
log.write('Check1\n')  
log.write('Check2\n')
log.write('Check3\n')
log.write('Check4\n')
```

On the 2494th iteration, the last entry in the log file is "Check2". If I make some tweaks to the function it will stop at Check 4; if I make other tweaks it will stop at iteration 2493 but stop at "Check1" or even make it all the way to the end of the function.

I thought the problem might have something to do with memory from the log file, but even when I comment out the log lines the code still stops on the 2494th line (once again, irrespective of the text that's actually contained in that line) or the 2493rd line, depending on the changes that I make.

No matter what I do, execution stops, then memory used according to Task Manager runs up to 100%. It's important to note that the memory DOES NOT increase substantially until AFTER the execution gets stuck.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this? I don't see anything wrong with the code and the fact that it stops executing after a certain number of actions indicates that I'm hitting some sort of fundamental limit that I'm not aware of.

Comment: This (the fixed iterations count) makes me think of something like recursion limit, then PyCham freezes trying to process the huge stack trace info ??

Comment: In that case the user will receive an alert before it stops; the maximum recursion depth can even be stopped. In this case the memory just expands forever with no further execution on the code

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using sys.getsizeof. Something must be happening to that dict that increases memory like crazy. Something else to try is using your regular terminal/cmd. Otherwise, I'd want to see a little bit more of the code.

Also, instead of using i += 1, you can enumerate your for loop.

```
for i, line in enumerate(line_list):
```

Hopefully some of that helps.

(Sorry, not enough rep to comment)

Comment: I used this on the dictionary and its memory allocation never goes above 9320 bytes. Also the "get_label" function returned False for the previous 1000+ iterations so the dictionary's size is not the culprit. I'm hesitant to post more code since the "get_label" function is >250 lines long and refers to several other functions as well. I'm just wondering if anyone has seen a problem like this before and what they did to solve it - the huge memory is not being allocated to any variables in any function so I don't even know where to start. I'll try creating a new virtual environment through CMD

Comment: @Helios I know PyCharm's terminal is takes up a bit of memory. Did you try using just your own terminal/cmd? Is there anything else in your `get_label` method? Like beside the logging? If not, just comment out that label_tmp and see if that's got any usage.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to provide the solution months after asking. As most experienced coders probably know, the write() function only adds the output to a buffer. So if an infinite loop occurs before the buffer can clear (it only clears once every few lines, depending on the size of the buffer) then any lines still in the buffer won't print to the file. This made it appear to be a different type of issue (I thought the issue was ~20-30 lines before the actual flawed line; the buffer cleared on different lines depending on how I changed the code, which explains why the log file ended on different lines when unrelated changes were made). When I replaced "write" with "print" I was able to identify the exact line in the code that caused the loop.

To avoid a dummy situation like this, I recommend making a custom "write_to_file" function that includes a "flush" so that it writes every single line to the log file. I also added other types of protection to that custom "write_to_file" function such as not writing if the file exceeds a certain size, etc.